# RESTAngular PUT not saving entire payload

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am trying to make a PUT request using RESTAngular. I am fairly new to Angular as well as RESTAngular.

#### Following is code snippet which works.

```
$scope.itemToUpdate = Restangular.all($scope.slug);
$scope.itemToUpdate.getList().then(function(items){
    var item = items.one($routeParams.id);
    item.name = $scope.singular.name;
    item.description = $scope.singular.description;
    item.put();
});
```

#### This doesn't work.

```
    $scope.itemToUpdate = Restangular.all($scope.slug);
    $scope.itemToUpdate.getList().then(function(items){
        var item = items.one($routeParams.id);
        item = $scope.singular;
        item.put();
    });
```

Don't know what am I doing wrong.

`$scope.singular` gets it data initially as following. `Restangular.one('roles', $routeParams.id).getList().$object`.

Basically idea is to update this model from form and also prepopulate the form with relevant data when slug matches the id. I can change the way things are wired up if required. So feel free to suggest best practices.

#### Edit 2

This official demo is very helpful in solving the issue.
http://plnkr.co/edit/d6yDka?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When Restangular returns resouce array\object it adds some methods on the object such as `put` which has been wired up to update the object on put call to server.

In second case you are assigning `item=$scope.singular`. `$scope.singular` may not be a Restangular object and hence does not work.

Comment: I've updated the question on how `$scope.singular` is being set. It's clearly a data type mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

This official demo is very helpful in solving the issue. http://plnkr.co/edit/d6yDka?p=preview

Comment: this demo is outdated.  The lib's author has c&p'd the src for Restangular into the demo rather than linking to the current stable source.